# How to filter Pandas table by remote datasource?

Tags: pandas, jupyter-notebook

Is it possible to load data from MySQL database table(phone) to Pandas then filter table by these data?

To get rows only where column(phone) is presented in loaded data from MySQL?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your best bet will to use SQLAlchemy to connect to the MySQL DB, and from there you can use pandas to filter the phone column `df.dropna(inplace = True)`